# How to set timeout for /_next/image?

Tags: next.js

While using Next.js, I noticed some of my images have been transformed into `/_next/image?url=https:%2F%2Fimage-c.weimobwmc.com%2Ffe-website%2F5521fe8369c54409ad0b17e0659c92a4.png&w=32&q=75` (originally `https://image-c.weimobwmc.com/fe-website/5521fe8369c54409ad0b17e0659c92a4.png`) and occasionally it results at timeout for unknown reasons leaving service warnings in my system. Is it possible to either completely turn off the proxy for image or set a timeout for these proxy request?

Comment: _"occasionally it results at timeout for unknown reasons"_ - have you tried investigating why those timeouts occur?

Comment: It looks like Next.js sometimes would take a long time to process images.

Comment: Even a 10px image would take 2 minutes, and it happens occasionally, around once in 1000 tries.

Comment: We experience the same timeouts on `/_next/image?` (on the same frequency), and we do not figured out why.
Do you succeed to understand and fix what it causing this ?

Comment: Any updates here? Did you find any solution?